# how to using spring-cloud-config server to inject properties into existing xml files

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

My xml looks like this:

```
<bean id="dataSourceMaster" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://${db.url}?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF8&amp;autoReconnect=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"></property>
    ...
</bean>
```

In spring.xml, I tried this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${spring.cloud.config.sync.url}" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

but the cloud-config server uses basic-auth, and I tried to set
spring.cloud.config.sync.url=http://user:pass@url/config-name/profile/label

, but app on start returns 401 error.

How to solve this problem, or is there a graceful way to solve injecting properties into existing xml from cloud-config server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can't inject ${...} expression in `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. There is already a [JIRA Ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4953) for this. However, there are workarounds available in this ticket which should solve your problem.